# need to return response with message on set_password request using Djoser jwt

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, djoser

I made a serializer, and view to override the set_password, but got the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SetPasswordView' from 'djoser.views'

here is serializer:

```
class CustomSetPasswordSerializer(SetPasswordSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        attrs["message"] = "Your password has been changed successfully."
        return attrs
```

Djoser settings:

```
DJOSER = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'username',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
            'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
            'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
            'set_password': 'accounts.serializers.CustomSetPasswordSerializer',
        },
}
```

```
from djoser.views import SetPasswordView
from rest_framework.response import Response
class CustomSetPasswordView(SetPasswordView):
    serializer_class = CustomSetPasswordSerializer

    def action(self, serializer):
        self.request.user.set_password(serializer.data["new_password"])
        self.request.user.save()
        return Response({"message": serializer.data["message"]})
```

I need when make a request to set_password, return a response with a message

`attrs["message"] = "Your password has been changed successfully.`

Now the response is 204 No content